# ember validation with if condition not working as expected

Tags: ember.js

I am using dockyard/ember-validation to validate controller properties, but I haven;t been able to get it working as I expected it to. So I have basically toggle effect on checkboxes, and I have defined 2 validation rules and only one of them should be executed/validated when user toggles between the checkboxes.
My validation rules are defined as :

```
validations: {

            "instructions": {
                format: {
                    if: 'inlineSource',
                    'with': /^(?!\s*$).+/
                }
            },
            "externalSourceValue": {
                format: {
                    if: 'externalSource',
                    'with': /^(?!\s*$).+/
                }
            }
        }
```

Here either inlineSource is true or externalSource is true, but both will never be simultaneously true. I would expect only one validation rule to be exercised, but it seems both are getting run disregarding the if condition there.

Here is the jsbin to the issue: http://jsbin.com/ODAmukOM/1/

Follow these steps :
1) click on External Website
2) set the input field value to empty
3) click to Content I Specify
4) the validation sets the controller to invalid state

Thanks, 
Dee

Answer (score 0):

you are adding 2 format validations,

instructions is valid if `inlineSource` **&&** `/^(?!\s*$).+/`

really your logic needs to be more like this

```
"instructions": {
   format: {
      if:  function(object, validator) {
        console.log('inlineSource',object);
        if(!object.get('inlineSource')){
          return (object.get('instruction') || '').match(/^(?!\s*$).+/);
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
 }
```

unfortunately validation is only run when you change properties, so you change `instruction`  validation is run and it's invalid, you then switch (flipping `inlineSource`), but validation won't happen again.  At this point you'll need to manually run validations to get that validation checked again.  good luck

Comment: I am manually running validation with disableSave function which observes both inlineSource and externalSource. But still I cant get it to work!